# Empty ItemsControl causing memory leak in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am facing a slightly weird problem with WPF.

We are using a TabControl with a ContentTemplateSelector to render the different pages:

```
<Window x:Class="LeakTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeakTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template0">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock>Template0</TextBlock>
            <local:DebugControl/>
            <!-- DebugControl stops leaking if ItemsControl or AlternationCount attribute is removed -->
            <ItemsControl AlternationCount="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
        <TextBlock>Template1</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems, Mode=OneTime}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}">            
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Index}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

With this CodeBehind:

```
namespace LeakTest
{
    public class TabItem {
        public int Index {
            get; private set;
        }

        public TabItem(int index)
        {
            this.Index = index;
        }
    };

    public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            TabItem i = (TabItem)item;

            Window win = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            return win.FindResource("Template"+i.Index) as DataTemplate;
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private List<TabItem> tabItems = new List<TabItem>() { new TabItem(0), new TabItem(1) };
        public IList<TabItem> TabItems => tabItems;
    }
}
```

DebugControl is simply an empty UserControl. As expected, a new instance of DebugControl is created every time the first tab is opened. However, as soon as I add the empty ItemsControls on the first tab, the UserControl instance is never freed:
[image: Screenshot from VS memory profiler]

Is this a bug in ItemsControl or am I doing something else wrong that's causing this?

Comment: How you conclude it is never freed? Where did you look?

Comment: I tried implementing an empty finalizer, which isn't called until the entire application closes. Furthermore, the snapshot from the memory profiler also shows the ItemsControl instance remaining after the tab is switched.
This behavior does not occur if I remove the ItemsControl or the AlternationCount parameter.

Comment: I guess you are aware of the garbage collection?

Comment: In what way aware? That it may take some time? Yes. The garbage collection just never happens, because that EventHandler still has a reference to the ItemsControl.